# M2.3.5 Order Confirmation Email - product upload file link not rendering a tag

Tags: magento2, custom-options, email-templates, magento2.3.5-p1

I've recently updated to version 2.3.5 and when order confirmation emails are sent the link to the uploaded file used to work correctly but is now showing the a tag rather than rendering a link, I'm struggling to find why this is happening?

Below is the source code from an email, in my theme I've made no changes to the email design and it's based on the blank theme.

```
<em style="font-style: italic;">Upload a File or Image</em></strong></dt>
<dd style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 8px;">
&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.example.com/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/624/key/caeebb9b/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;B75856C.png&lt;/a&gt; 229 x 292 px. </dd></dl>
```